# How do you applying parent category to items in subcategory?

Tags: excel, magento, categories, product

While I was going through my products I realized when I clicked on a category it doesn't show the full item list. When I went to the back end I realized that the main parent categories were not selected for certain product. Is there a way to easily add the parent category to the item? I have limited knowledge of magento and excel, I've tried adding the parent categories to the items in excel but it isn't the most efficient way. Any help and suggestions is much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just anchor the categories so that they will show the product that is under them and every category that is under them.

```
 $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
         ->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("gt" => 2))
         ->setOrder('entity_id')
         ;

foreach($categories as $category) {
                $category->setIncludeInMenu(1);
                $category->setIsActive(1);
                $category->setIsAnchor(1);
                $category->save()
                }
```

If you set the category to be an Anchor the layered navigation (see How Does Layered Navigation Work in Magento? for a look at the layered navigation) will display the sub-categories of this category in the layered navigation. The layered navigation then takes all the products underneath, including ones in the sub-categories, and displays all the filterable attributes of those products. If you do not set the category as an Anchor it will not display the filterable attributes in the layered navigation.

This tab can be found in Manage Categories > some_category > Design tab > Is Anchor